# Trademark and other characters not working since Mojave update

Tags: keyboard, mojave, keybindings, input-source, text-input

Prior to the Mojave update, I could type Shift+Alt+2 to produce a trademark symbol (tm superscript). This, and others (Shift+Alt+{1-6,q,p,h,j,k,l,n,m,§}) do not work any more.

Is this intentional? If so, that sucks. If not, is this a known bug?

I'm using a Macbook 2015 if that makes any difference. I also found this question very difficult to search for ("shift+alt characters", "trademark symbol mojave", etc yielded no results, so apologies if it's a duplicate).

Edit: I've tested some more and it turns out this also affects regular Alt+ keys: e, r, p, s, f, h, j, k, l, n, §

Comment: What input source do you normally use?  With US, ™ is made by Alt + 2, not Shift + Alt + 2.  British perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Go to system prefs/keyboard/input sources and make sure that ONLY US or ABC or British is on the list.  Remove any others, especially Unicode Hex if present.